# What legal protection can someone ask for against a bully in Canada?

Tags: canada, harassment

What legal protection can someone ask for against a bully?

bullies in

- workplace
- school
- college
- neighbor

and, so on.

Can a victim go to police?

**N.B.** Bullying means making fun of, mocking on a regular basis.

**N.B.** Suppose, some specific class-mates/colleagues make fun of me in the class, in any public place on a regular basis.

Comment: You should be more specific about the form of bullying. Snide remarks versus assault have a different legal status (depending on jurisdiction, of course).

Comment: This is not really possible to answer without knowing which country or state you are asking about (different places have different legal systems) and without a more detailed description of the bullying conduct because that is not a well defined term and can mean different things to different people. Normally laws ban certain kinds of conduct, not a status like "being a bully".

Comment: @ohwilleke the concepts of "workplace bullying" are recognized in the laws of many jurisdictions under Work Health and Safety Law - this usually extends to non-workers in the workplace like students in a school or college.

Comment: @DaleM It isn't that certain kinds of conduct aren't prohibited. It is that "bullying" is not consistently defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a victim go to police?
>
> N.B. Bullying means making fun of, mocking on a regular basis.
>
> N.B. Suppose, some specific class-mates/colleagues make fun of me in
>   the class, in any public place on a regular basis.

Probably not. And very likely, not via the police or even a temporary restraining order. If there is a remedy it would mostly likely be through the educational institution's or workplace's procedures. Barring that, probably via a lawsuit claiming harassment, but often only for specific reasons (e.g. race, gender, disability).